# How to match exactly one colon in a timestamp and convert it to period?

Tags: python, regex

I'm having an issue with matching exactly one colon towards the tail end of a timestamp value. I want to match this colon exactly and then convert to a period. I have tried several ways to try to match this colon exactly, but to no avail.

Here's an example: 02:44:05:406 -> 02:44:05.406

I created the following regex: :\d+$ -> this will match :406 towards the end of the timestamp.

I tried a different approach: \d+:\d+$ -> this matches 02:44, 44:05, 05:406

I even tried this one: [^\d+] -> this matches all three colons :

However, I want the last colon - 02:44:05:406 and replace that with a "."

Any ideas on how to do this? I'm using Python 3 and regex.

EDIT: Removing ** from the third colon (e.g. **:**) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is regex mandatory?

Comment: Your first regex is already matching what needs to be matched, it just needs a capturing group. `re.sub(r':(\d+)$', r'.\1', s)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If regex is not mandatory, you could just use [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit) with `maxsplit` option:

```
>>> s = '02:44:05**:**406'
>>> '.'.join(s.rsplit(':', 1))
02:44:05**.**406
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this as your regex

```
r'^(.*):'
```

Match as many characters as possible up to the last `:` and capture them

Then your substitution should be

```
'\1.'
```

all the stuff captured followed by a dot

so your code looks like

```
re.sub(r'^(.*):', '\1.', text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.rpartition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition) to split the string on the final colon, then [str.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to create the new string.

```
>>> ts = '02:44:05:406'
>>> a, sep, b = ts.rpartition(':')
>>> res = '.'.join((a, b))
>>> res
'02:44:05.406'
```

Or you could use string formatting to create the new string:

```
>>> res = '{}.{}'.format(a, b)
>>> res
'02:44:05.406'
```